# Processing items in pandas groupby slow? Should we use hashmaps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a pandas dataframe of voter registration data. What we have done is follows :

1. Group voters by their address - this yields groups in a dataframe
   that we can then process.
2. Given these groups we now iterate through each of them, where each
   group has two people of different gender we probably classify them
   as a couple.
3. If we have a couple we further separate them into those that have
   same or different political party affiliation. In other words Democrat-Democrat, Republic-Democrat, etc.

The issue - speed!

Merely processing 58000 groups takes close to 5 minutes. I am in gradschool and I spoke to my professor, he essentially told me to use a hashmap. From what I can see on other stackoverflow searches we can use to_dict and list to get the work done, the format/syntax of this is unclear.

```
temp2['All'] = temp2['Residence Address Line 1'].str.cat(temp2[['Residence Address Line 2']], sep=' - ')
df=temp2.groupby('All')

couples1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Voter_ID_Male", "Name_First_Male", "Name_Last_Male", "Birth_Date_Male", "Party_Affiliation_Male","Voter_ID_Female",  "Name_First_Female", "Name_Last_Female", "Birth_Date_Female", "Party_Affiliation_Female"])
couples2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Voter_ID_Male", "Name_First_Male", "Name_Last_Male", "Birth_Date_Male", "Party_Affiliation_Male","Voter_ID_Female",  "Name_First_Female", "Name_Last_Female", "Birth_Date_Female", "Party_Affiliation_Female"])

for name,group in df:



    if counter%30000 == 0 :
      print("Processed {} of {} items".format(counter,df.ngroups) )
    counter += 1

    #continue

    if group.shape[0]==2 and group[group.Gender == 'F'].shape[0] == 1 and group[group.Gender == 'M'].shape[0] == 1:

       #Start processing ...
```

Comment: I did away with pandas and used a simple dictionary of list. What used to take 12 hrs now takes 24 minutes.